# correctly recally any dynamodb data with alexa query

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I've created a skill with the help of a few people on this site.

I have a database and what I want to do is ask Alexa to recall data from my database. I.e. by asking for films from a certain date

The issue im having at the moment is I have defined my partition key and it works correctly for one of my items in my table and will read the message for that specific key, but anything else i search it gives me the same response as the one item that works. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Here is how i have defined my table:

```js
var AWSregion = 'us-east-1';  // us-east-1
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dbClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({
    region: "'us-east-1'"
});

let handleCinemaIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  let params = {
    TableName: "dataset",
    Key: {
        name: 'taken',
        year: '2011'
    }
  };
  dbClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       // failed to read from table for some reason..
       console.log('failed to load data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       // let skill tell the user that it couldn't find the data 
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "the data could not be loaded from your database",
          endSession: true
       });
    } else {
       console.log('loaded data item:\n' + JSON.stringify(data.Item, null, 2));
       // assuming the item has an attribute called "message"..
       sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: data.Item.yea,
          endSession: true
       });
    }
  });
};


function sendResponse(context, callback, responseOptions) {
  if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    context.succeed(buildResponse(responseOptions));
  } else {
    callback(null, buildResponse(responseOptions));
  }
}

function buildResponse(options) {
  var alexaResponse = {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.output}</prosody></speak>`
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };
  if (options.repromptText) {
    alexaResponse.response.reprompt = {
      outputSpeech: {
        "type": "SSML",
        "ssml": `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${options.reprompt}</prosody></speak>`
      }
    };
  }
  return alexaResponse;
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    var request = event.request;
    if (request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
        output: "welcome to my skill. what do you want to find?",
        endSession: false
      });
    }
    else if (request.type === "IntentRequest") {
      let options = {};         
      if (request.intent.name === "cinema") {
        handleCinemaIntent(context, callback);
      } else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.StopIntent" || request.intent.name === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "ok. good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
      else if (request.intent.name === "AMAZON.HelpIntent") {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "you can ask me about films",
          reprompt: "what can I help you with?",
          endSession: false
        });
      }
      else {
        sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
        });
      }
    }
    else if (request.type === "SessionEndedRequest") {
      sendResponse(context, callback, ""); // no response needed
    }
    else {
      // un unexpected request type received.. just say I don't know..
      sendResponse(context, callback, {
          output: "I don't know that one! Good bye!",
          endSession: true
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error by logging it and sending back an failure
    console.log('Unexpected error occurred in the skill handler!', e);
    if(typeof callback === 'undefined') {
       context.fail("Unexpected error");
    } else {
       callback("Unexpected error");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: In the code snippet above, you query using the following key 
`Key: {
        name: 'taken',
        year: '2011'
}`
Is "name" the sort key and "year" the partition key?  From your earlier questions it seemed like the keys were "date" and "filmname"

Also, in the response you output `data.Item.yea` is that a typo, or do you actually have an attribute called `yea` on your item?

Comment: 2nd question:  in your skill interaction model, it looks like you have defined a custom intent called `cinema`, have you also defined custom slots to go with it? If so, what are the custom slot names? If not, you should define a "date" custom slot and a "name" custom slot so that the skill can determine what film and what date you are looking for.

Comment: @MikeDinescu name is my partition key and sort key is year. I'd changed this after i changed my dynamodb table, also yes it was a typo in my output which i'd corrected. I havent defined my custom slots, im not entirely sure how to do this, do i define every single name i will be using? I understand for the date slot i can use AMAZON.DATE? or am i wrong?

Comment: can you give an example of one or two queries you would expect a user to make to the skill? For instance, would you expect users to say something like "Alexa, what day is 'Wrinkle In Time' playing?" - if so, then you should define a slot called 'MovieName' and add all movie names you have in your database to it. This part, I agree, doesn't scale well, but for now it's the best you have.

Comment: @MikeDinescu well initially the data and setup I had was for movies as this was what my sample data was. But my real data is to do with machine states and runtimes, so ill have 3 different machine states (Cycling, Loading and Starved) and different run times start and end consisting of data and time. Id like to call Alexa to find the state of a machine at differnt times, e.g. "Alexa, what was the state at 1pm on 19/03/18'.

Comment: in this case the question you posted about how to model your data in DynamoDB and the answers you received aren't necessarily correct because the problem is different. in this case, the correct primary key for you is date. The range key is time. And the state is just an attribute. Recreate your table to use date as primary key, and time as rage key. Then, the interaction model should have a date & time slot, with sample utterances like "what was the sate at DATE_TIME", where DATE_TIME is a date & time slot.

Comment: @mikedinescu thanks again for your reply, i gave this a try and setup my table to have primary as date, time as sort ket, and the another column to have incident. my sample utterance is 'what was the state at {AMAZON.TIME} on {AMAZON.DATE}', ive also updated my dynamodb table in lambda and linked the table. the response i now get it 'There was a problem with the requested skill's response'

Comment: @MikeDinescu Hi again, can you explain if i've done my slot wrong?

Comment: Hi @zuba this is now a completely different question that we’re discussing in comments. Please don’t take this the wrong way but for these questions and answers to be useful to people you should ask a specific question each time. For now I will leave you with the following advice. Since you have modified the interaction model, try to get your skill working without using the database first. Log everything to cloudwatch and use those logs to understand what the input data looks like. Try to make your skill simply say back “you asked about the state at (input time) on (input date)”

Comment: @mikedinescu thats fine, i understand, thank you for your help!